# horizontal Multi-Selection in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a multi-selection that works in all modern browsers.
The problem is that it doesn't work as expected in Firefox.
In Chrome the overflow boxes breaks in to a new row but in Firefox the overflow stays hidden.

I know that it works in Chrome so if you use Chrome then you will see the result I want in Firefox.

Anyone knows a solution?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#data {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
 width:100vw;
}
select {
 padding:0;
 padding-left:1px;
 border:none;
 background-color:#eee;
 width:100%;
 white-space: normal;
 height:200px;
}
option {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background-color:white;
 margin-left:-1px;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div id="data">
 <select multiple size="1">
  <option>jan</option>
  <option>feb</option>
  <option>mar</option>
  <option>apr</option>
  <option>maj</option>
  <option>jun</option>
  <option>jul</option>
  <option>aug</option>
  <option>sep</option>
  <option>okt</option>
  <option>nov</option>
  <option>dec</option>
 </select>
</div>

</form>
```

Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zorja63m/)

Comment: What is it actually you want? Can you be a more specific? What doesn't work?

Comment: Whops I edited the question. I missed a part when I was forced to make the text longer to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some google research and it doesn't seems to be any solution.
It's simply how Firefox works.